# Is it possible to use angular virtual list with rows of items?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

using angular 8, i have a list of  thousands of cards which i want to view them effectivly while scrolling, with 4 or more cards per row (using wrap) and still use the virtual scroll feature. as far as my tries go i can have more then 1 item per row.
here is my code for reference,

```
 <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="200" class="viewport" >
     <div class="card" *cdkVirtualFor="let c of cards ; templateCacheSize: 50">
            <img class="image" src="{{cdnAddress}}/{{set1Address}}/img/cards/{{c.cardCode}}.png">
     </div>
 </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

Comment: This should work w/o an issue as long as the `card` class has a fixed height, what's the problem and are you receiving any errors? cdkVirtualFor expects a set height for each row and virtually scrolls them with lazy loading regardless of what is actually in them.

Comment: there is no errors, its just that without the virtual scroll i have wrap list scroll with 5 cards each row, and in the virtual scroll i cant have more then 1 card in a row.

Comment: You can calculate # of items per row, and reduce your item size by that number (card height of 200 w/ 5 cards per row is 200 / 5 = item size 40)